# Adding node in xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have a simple xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<subscribers>
    <user>
        <email>user1@gmail.com</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <email>aaaa@gmail.com</email>
    </user>
</subscribers>
```

And I simply need to add a new user to the subscribers. I tried a lot of different solutions and I keep getting errors and bugs. I read all others posts here about similar problem and links to php.net do not help.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("caus_sub_data.xml");
$subscribers = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$user = $subscribers->addChild('user');
$user->addChild('email', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaa@sdsd.com');
echo $subscribers->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to add a child to the first movie in your XML file, but there are no movies. Try:

```
$user = $subscribers->addChild('user');
```

Edit: `simplexml_load_file` returns a simple XML element, so the line `$subscribers = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);` is unnecessary. You can do:

```
$subscribers = simplexml_load_file("caus_sub_data.xml");
```

Comment: `$subscribers->asXml('caus_sub_data.xml');` To save the updated XML back to the file.